# Check whether one value exists in a row, all columns combined together in R

Tags: r

I want to create a data frame which has got 5 columns (Ball1, Ball2,Ball3,Ball4 and Ball5) and each column can take either of 3 values (Box1, Box2,Box3)
The code for the dataframe generation is as below:

```
iterations = 10
variables = 5

output <- matrix(ncol=variables, nrow=iterations)

for(i in 1:iterations){
  output[i,] <- sample(c("Box1","Box2","Box3"), 5, replace=T)
  
}
output <- data.frame(output)
colnames(output)[1] <- "Ball1"
colnames(output)[2] <- "Ball2"
colnames(output)[3] <- "Ball3"
colnames(output)[4] <- "Ball4"
colnames(output)[5] <- "Ball5"
output
```

Now I want to create a 6th column "All_Boxes_Present" where I want see if for a particular row if all boxes are present at least once. If present, then the 6th column should be 1 else 0.
Below is a sample output:

Expected output Table

[image: Output table]

Answer (score 5):

We can use `apply` in base R to check if `all` the boxes are present in each row and assign 1/0 accordingly.

```
all_boxes <- c("Box1","Box2","Box3")
output$all_present <- +(apply(output, 1, function(x) all(all_boxes %in% x)))
```

---

In `dplyr` we can do it with `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

output %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(all_box_present = +(all(all_boxes %in% c_across())))

# Ball1 Ball2 Ball3 Ball4 Ball5 all_box_present
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>           <int>
# 1 Box2  Box2  Box1  Box2  Box1                0
# 2 Box1  Box2  Box3  Box1  Box3                1
# 3 Box1  Box2  Box1  Box2  Box2                0
# 4 Box2  Box3  Box1  Box1  Box1                1
# 5 Box1  Box3  Box1  Box2  Box1                1
# 6 Box2  Box2  Box1  Box1  Box1                0
# 7 Box1  Box3  Box1  Box1  Box1                0
# 8 Box2  Box2  Box3  Box2  Box3                0
# 9 Box1  Box1  Box1  Box1  Box1                0
#10 Box3  Box1  Box1  Box3  Box3                0
```

`+` at the beginning changes logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to integers (`1`/`0`) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

We can use vectorized option with `Reduce` in `base R`

```
output$all_present <- +(Reduce(`&`, lapply(all_boxes, function(x)
              rowSums(output == x) > 0)))
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
output %>% 
   mutate(all_present = map(all_boxes, function(x) rowSums(x == .) %>%
         magrittr::is_greater_than(0)) %>%
         reduce(`&`) %>% as.integer)
```

#### data

```
all_boxes <- c("Box1","Box2","Box3")
```